# Query for largest ordered subset in a ordered selection

Tags: sql, oracle, subset

I have the result of a selection with columns (of type number) col1 and col2, ordered by col1; keeping the  order (by col1) fixed, I need to extract the subset of records that in col2 are still ordered; this subset must be the largest possible (it could even be the entire selection in case col2 is already ordered after col1 ordering). If more than one solution is possible, I need the solution having greatest col1 numbers.

For instance, if after ordering by col1 I have this col1-col2 records:

```
col1 - col2
0-1
3-2
4-14
5-4
7-10
```

...then I should select:

```
0-1
3-2
5-4
7-10
```

...being the largest ordered set for col2 formed by 4 elements: 1,2,4,10;
col1 can have duplicates, col2 can have duplicates too, and every item in the longest sequence must be greater than the previous one (not greater than or equal to it).
The longest sequence doesn't have to start at the first item.
I need a query or a pl/sql procedure in oracle 11

Comment: This problem has a name:  The Longest Increasing Subsequence.  There is an efficient solution, but I have no idea if it can be readily implemented in SQL.  You can start with the Wikipedia page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

The following solves your problem in a SQL vendor agnostic (*standard*) way:

```
-- drop table mytable;
/*
create table mytable(col1 integer, col2 integer);
insert into mytable values(0, 2);
insert into mytable values(0, 14);
insert into mytable values(1, 2);
insert into mytable values(1, 14);
insert into mytable values(7, 4);
insert into mytable values(9, 5);
insert into mytable values(10, 6);
*/

SELECT *
FROM mytable cur
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT col1
  FROM mytable nex
  WHERE nex.col1 = (SELECT MIN(aux.col1) FROM mytable aux WHERE aux.col1 > cur.col1)
  AND nex.col2 <= cur.col2
)
ORDER BY cur.col1, cur.col2;
```

This query was tested for Oracle 11gR2 on the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3128/1).

Comment: You missed `INTO` in insert statements and I wonder what SQL standard allows non-alphanumeric as the first character in object names along with strange `int` datatype. Being agnostic does not necessarily mean being "doesn't-work-on-any-database". :) Or did you mean agnostic as kind of pseudo-code just to show the approach?

Comment: n1 stands for col1 and n2 stands for col2? What does it mean 1=1?

Comment: Hi, @user3290675, you are right, n1 used to stand for col1 and n2 to col2, but I renamed the columns to match the names you used. The `1=1` is just _syntactic sugar_, it has no meaning, but allow that every condition to start with a `AND` (it's just a style preference I have).

Comment: Hi, @YaroslavShabalin, since loading the table was not the focus of the question I didn't bother to be strict here and used the T-SQL dialect (it was faster for me to test).

Comment: In this dialect, `INT` is an alias for `INTEGER`, the `INTO` is optional and the `#` before the table name states for a temporary table. I am sure you can run the sample with very minor modifications to suit your specific DBMS, since it relies on SQL and not on a proprietary programming language (as T-SQL or PL).

Comment: There is something going wrong... for instance if col1-col2 is: 0-2,0-14,1-2,1-14,7-4,9-5,10-6 I obtain only 7-4,9-5,10-6 instead of expected 1-2,7-4,9-5,10-6

Comment: @user3290675: So `col1` can have duplicates, is that right?

Comment: Hi, @user3290675, I dind't expect duplicates for col1 and used it to identify entities (either to sort and to remove the sequence breakers) ... I guess, thought, the script can be adapted. Do you have any other constraints and data to test?

Comment: There are no other constraints; but as you can see in the last example I could have two solutions: 1-2,7-4,9-5,10-6 and 0-2,7-4,9-5,10-6; I have to choose the first because 1>0 comparing 1-2 to 0-2.

Comment: Hi, @user3290675, I edited the query and the results are consistent to your test case (returns 1-2, 7-4, 9-5, 10-6).

Comment: The combination: 0-10,27-12,34-13,37-1,38-2,38-14,39-21 gives 0-10,27-12,37-1,38-2,38-14,39-21 instead of 0-10,27-12,34-13,38-14,39-21

Comment: You are right: the longest sequence doesn't have to start at the first item

Comment: Hi, @user3290675, unfortunately my suggestion does not apply to sequences that can _skip_ some out-of-sequence elements. It also cannot find multiple sequences and neither it definitely cannot calculate the greatest sequence from a collection of sequences.

Comment: Has my question some ambiguity? Or sql is not enough powerful?

Comment: If there were no duplicates would the last query work?

Comment: Hi, @user3290675, I think I didn't fully understand your question when I began. I presented a query that will return the records whose col2 is a sequence of non-continuous increasing numbers, starting with the value of the first record. I did it in _best effort_ base and tried all use cases you provided, but I cannot guarantee its completeness. I'm happy if I helped you, but this problem is not so trivial (it's a **good** one!) and I currently I have little time to spare.

Comment: About SQL, unfortunately I see many people underestimating it. It's an excellent language for set-related problems and I _believe_ a big range of problems can be elegantly expressed in set therms. Maybe for this problem you'l need a programming language (like PL), but please keep in mind that if you'd prefer approach any issue in a procedural way, SQL is _not_ the way to go. Good coding!

Comment: I haven't found anywhere in internet an implementation of longest non-decreasing subsequence written in vba for excel... any suggestion?